# Get current width and height of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two div's that can re-size after clicking on the plus or minus buttons.
Not the current situation has the words 'Width' and 'Height' displayed in between.

Instead of the words I would like to show the current size.
So if I press twice on the plus (making the div 20px's bigger) I want to show that by visually seeing the number grow with 20px's.

```
$(".SmallerWidth").click(function () {
    $("#div1").animate({
        'width': '-=10px'
    });
    $("#div2").animate({
        'width': '-=10px'
    });
});
```

I've made a [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p9x68vnf/1/).

Comment: Not clear what you expect to display. Eacvh `div` width and height or the incremented number???

Comment: I meant each width and height of the different div's. Sorry if that wasn't clear. https://jsfiddle.net/p9x68vnf/5/ has the answer that I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the feedle: https://jsfiddle.net/p9x68vnf/2/

```
$("#div1").animate({'width':'+=10px'}).html($('#div1').width());
$("#div2").animate({'width':'+=10px'}).html($('#div2').width());
```

**UPD:**

There is what actually you want:

https://jsfiddle.net/p9x68vnf/5/

Comment: Thank you, but how do I get it between the plus and minus button?

Comment: It's hard because it's between the buttons , add a holder between the buttons which you `.empty()`  then add the new width

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You should put text between span or any other tag. And display it's width and height.

```js
$(".SmallerWidth").click(function(){
 $("#div1").animate({'width':'-=10px'});
    $("#div2").animate({'width':'-=10px'});
    disp();
});   

$(".BiggerWidth").click(function(){
    $("#div1").animate({'width':'+=10px'});
    $("#div2").animate({'width':'+=10px'});
    disp();
});

$(".SmallerHeight").click(function(){
 $("#div1").animate({'height':'-=10px'});
    $("#div2").animate({'height':'-=10px'});
    disp();
});

$(".BiggerHeight").click(function(){
 $("#div1").animate({'height':'+=10px'});
    $("#div2").animate({'height':'+=10px'});
    disp();
});

function disp()
{
$(".wi").text("First Width " + $('#div1').width() + " Second Width " + $('#div2').width());
$(".he").text("First Height " + $('#div1').height() + " Second Height " + $('#div2').height());
}
```

```css
#div1{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#39ACC7;
    
}
#div2{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background: #B2C2D1;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">First </div>
<div id="div2">Second </div>


</br></br>
<button class="SmallerWidth"> - </button>  <span class="wi"> Width (this is where I want to show the current size) </span>  <button class="BiggerWidth"> + </button></br>
<button class="SmallerHeight"> - </button> <span class="he"> Height (this is where I want to show the current size) </span>  <button class="BiggerHeight"> + </button>
```

Your updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p9x68vnf/6/)

Comment: What about div2 displayed size? OP's question is unclear imho

Comment: Yes that's almost what I wanted. Sorry if it was unclear. You can check what I meant here: https://jsfiddle.net/p9x68vnf/5/
It starts counting at 100 but after the first click the size is already 110 ;) But thank you for taking the effort

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the current width and height of the element, you can use width() and height() functions:

```
var width = $('#div1').width(); 
var height= $('#div1').height();
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p9x68vnf/4/)

```
   $(".SmallerWidth").click(function(){
    $("#div1").animate({'width':'-=10px'});
    $("#div2").animate({'width':'-=10px'});
    resize();
});   

$(".BiggerWidth").click(function(){
    $("#div1").animate({'width':'+=10px'});
    $("#div2").animate({'width':'+=10px'});
    resize();
});

$(".SmallerHeight").click(function(){
    $("#div1").animate({'height':'-=10px'});
    $("#div2").animate({'height':'-=10px'});
    resize();
});

$(".BiggerHeight").click(function(){
    $("#div1").animate({'height':'+=10px'});
    $("#div2").animate({'height':'+=10px'});
    resize();
});

function resize(){
   $('#width-total').empty().append("First Width:"+$("#div1").width()+"px Second Width:"+$("#div2").width()+"px");
    $('#height-total').empty().append("First height:"+$("#div1").height()+"px Second height:"+$("#div2").height()+"px");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".SmallerWidth").click(function(){

    $("#div1").animate({'width':'-=10px'}).html($("#div1").width());
    $("#div2").animate({'width':'-=10px'}).html($("#div2").width());
});   

$(".BiggerWidth").click(function(){


    $("#div1").animate({'width':'+=10px'}).html($("#div1").width());
    $("#div2").animate({'width':'+=10px'}).html($("#div2").width());
});

$(".SmallerHeight").click(function(){
    $("#div1").animate({'height':'-=10px'}).html($("#div1").height());
    $("#div2").animate({'height':'-=10px'}).html($("#div2").height());
});

$(".BiggerHeight").click(function(){

    $("#div1").animate({'height':'+=10px'}).html($("#div1").height());
    $("#div2").animate({'height':'+=10px'}).html($("#div2").height());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use height() and width()

see this link

[Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

[Width](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

[height](http://api.jquery.com/height/)